# Where can I find examples of txout_to_script and tx_out_to_scripthash Transactions?

Tags: transaction-data, txo-set

I'm creating a golang monero tools suite and I need some data to test against. Unfortunately, I don't know where I can find txout_to_script/txout_to_scripthash/txin_to_script/txin_to_scripthash transactions.

Some transaction hashes that I can look up locally would be a perfect answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nowhere. These are not implemented, and will be rejected by the network.

Comment: Oh really? None of them are used in any way? Even on testnet?

Comment: As they are not implemented, they are not used, even on testnet.